# How to restart autoplay audio / video after leave slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I use fullPage.js, I wonder if you know how to fix this. I would like to have restart autoplay after leave slider, when come back slider start new video / audio again if you know what I mean.

HTML:

```
<div class="slide">
   <video loop muted controls="false" data-autoplay>
     <source src="..." type="video/mp4">
     <source src="..." type="video/ogg">
   </video>
</div>
<div class="slide book-1">
   <audio controls="" data-autoplay>
     <source src="..." type="audio/ogg">
     <source src="..." type="audio/mpeg">
     Your browser does not support the audio element.
   </audio>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['#eee', '#fff'],
  anchors: ['firstPage', 'book-1']
   });
});
</script>
```

I looking forward to hearing from you :)

Thanks,

Shaun.

Comment: @on_marketing what do you mean? That when you come back to the page it resumes from where it left off?

Comment: Yes like start audio sound again :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/on_marketing/54dgj7qd/1/

Comment: see answer below.

Comment: The data-autoplay attribute was enough to get this working for me: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#auto-playpause-embedded-media

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `afterLoad` callback. In this you should restart the audio and video elements after they load.

The code should look something like this:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['red', 'green'],
  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    if (index === 1) {
      let video = document.getElementById('video');
      video.load();
      video.play();
    }

    if (index === 2) {
      let audio = document.getElementById('sound');
      audio.currentTime = 0
      audio.play();
    }
  }
});
```

See complete working example below.

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['red', 'green'],
  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    if (index === 1) {
      let video = document.getElementById('video');
      video.load();
      video.play();
    }

    if (index === 2) {
      let audio = document.getElementById('sound');
      audio.currentTime = 0
      audio.play();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.section {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <video id="video" loop muted controls="false" data-autoplay>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="slide">
      <audio id='sound' controls="" data-autoplay>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> Your browser does not support the audio element.
      </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">Two 2</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: When I scroll up slide how to stop audio sound?